# Why are our Platform Event EventUuids missing and how do we fix it?

Tags: integration, event, platform-event, event-monitoring

We have a bunch of Platform Event events which we are successfully sending out of Salesforce to Dynamics 365 by way of an "event bridge" which receives messages from Salesforce and places the messages on the Azure Service Bus.

We want to use the Event Uuid to track messages and confirm they have been received, as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_event_uuid.htm).

However, while the "event" data contains the "replayId", this is the only property "event" ever contains.  "EventUuid" is consistently missing from the messages we are receiving.

Using a debugger, we've confirmed our event bridge is not receiving this value and this is the only value missing from the messages it is receiving from Salesforce.

Is there something which needs to be configured on the Salesforce side to ensure the consumer will receive this value?  Could this be some permission problem?

Comment: I don't think this could be a permission problem (since EventUuid isn't actually a part of the event schema). Could you subscribe to the same HVPE using apex? and check if the EventUuid is missing even for internal subscribers? This could probably throw some light indicating if this is a platform defect.

Comment: @arut, I'm not entirely clear how you'd have us test in Apex.  The value is not-null, if that's what you mean.  Moreover, one of our developers who is presently on vacation was somehow able to see the EventUuid when somehow using the Salesforce Workbench to view Platform Events through "Generic Subscriptions".  (However, I couldn't get workbench to play with Platform Events at all.)

Comment: api version is 52 or greater?

Comment: Did you check the Apex API version number for the code that is publishing the events? I note that the documentation indicates it is only available from 52.0 onwards.

Comment: "You are able to get the EventUuid on the published event message but not **consistently** on the received event messages" >> Is my understanding of the problem statement correct? If not, then rest of this comment won't make much sense. If the problem lies with the event  bus, I believe only salesforce would be help. But to get a sense of whether the problem lies at **external** subscriber or at platform level, you can subscribe to the HVPE using apex (single HVPE will support multiple subscribers). ... contd in my next comment ...

Comment: The SF doc linked in your question gives apex code sample on how to get the EventUuid using apex (*internal subscriber*). For a given HVPE (single event), if you are able to get EventUuid in the internal subscriber but not in the external subscriber, then it at least confirms that EventUuid is sent to the event bus managed by Salesforce. This doesn't solve your problem entirely though and you might have to observe this for multiple event messages.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves, I suspect this might be the issue as (I remembered over the weekend) we haven't updated the endpoint in a long time.  I'll try updating this shortly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

As suspected by @Kris Goncalves, our solution was using an older API version (i.e. v49.0).

I bumped this up to v54.0 and the problem was resolved.